# How to get xdebug working on a manual compiled php 5.2 binary in debian squeeze

Tags: php, debian, xdebug

I am exploring a new server setup using Debian squeeze(6). From a former FreeBSD perspective I have to say I like the OS very much. The problem however is that the default PHP version is 5.3. Fixing this was not hard, since this is a general issue. I used the following guide

http://blog.davejamesmiller.com/2011/03/how-to-install-php-5-2-fastcgi-on-debian-6-0-squeeze

and managed to compile a working 5.2.17 binary. This binary has almost all functionality bundled except for Xdebug wich is vital for my development rig.

Now I have tried to manually compile Xdebug from source but it doesn't work for my 5.2 binary. Even temporarily replacing the systems phpize yields the same result.

Is there a solution for this problem? Like i.e: bundling xdebug during the php compiling?

My sincere appologies if my English is lacking. Any insights are welcome!

**[UPDATE]**
I was using the correct version of phpize (the one for PHP 5.2). But I found out that I had to additionally specify the

```
./configure --with-php-config=/full/path/to/php/bin/php-config
```

flag as well. It is operating perfectly now.

The issue is resolved.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? And what was the reason you replaced the phpize command?

Comment: As of debian squeeze php 5.3 is de default. The api version reported by phpize was ofcourse for php 5.3. While i need to compile a xdebug module for my 5.2 binary.

There are no errors, it just simply compiles for 5.3

Comment: Please select cweiske's answer as the answer if you think it was helpful for you. It will also mark your question as solved as it is now for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `phpize` command that comes with your php 5.2 installation. Also make sure you specify the php-config path when running `configure`.

Comment: How do I use the phpize that I have received while compiling 5.2 during the make of xdebug?

Comment: When I use that phpize i receive the following error: configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions

Comment: Please update your question with the current status and *show the output*.